# Make transaction fail right away if contention in Google Datastore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

In [Google Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore), if one transaction is reading and writing an entity and a different transaction tries to read and write to the same entity, the second transaction waits until the first one finishes before throwing an error. Once that error is thrown, you can retry the transaction.

Is there a way to have the second transaction throw an error as soon as it detects another transaction is accessing the same entity? I want my transaction to just fail right away and not retry, instead of waiting around.

Answer (score 0):

> If one transaction is reading and writing an entity and a different transaction tries to read and write to the same entity, the second transaction waits until the first one finishes before throwing an error. Once that error is thrown, you can retry the transaction.

Yes, this is exactly what it does.

> Is there a way to have the second transaction throw an error as soon as it detects another transaction is accessing the same entity?

That's the whole purpose, to *automatically* retry a transaction when it fails.

You added both [google-cloud-firestore](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore) and [google-cloud-datastore](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-datastore) tags to your question. So if you intend to use Firestore and you don't want any transaction retries, please note that newer versions of the Firestore SDK for Android allow the configuration of the number of retries. There is a [TransactionOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/TransactionOptions) class, which contains a field called [maxAttempts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/TransactionOptions#maxAttempts()). You can set it to zero, so cannot have any retires when a transaction fails.

Comment: My issue is that the second transaction waits a long time until it throws the error. While that second transaction is waiting, it is using up CPU time on the instance. I just want it to fail right away to avoid that. If you set the retry options to zero, it still waits around which is not good. I am on google cloud datastore.

Comment: It shouldn't wait a long time if you set it set `maxAttempts = 0`. Maybe there is something else in your code that produces that. However, I am not aware of another approach.

Comment: In datastore there is no `TransactionOptions`. As it says here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#uses_for_transactions "The Datastore API does not automatically retry transactions, but you can add your own logic to retry them, for instance to handle conflicts when another request updates the same entity at the same time." My issue is that long delay the transaction seems to be waiting around before ever throwing the error (at which point one may retry the transaction)

Comment: There is no TransactionOptions class because the API does not automatically retry. However, I don't fully understand what you mean by "at which point one may retry the transaction". How can a transaction be retried, when the API does not automatically do that?

Comment: "at which point one may retry the transaction" - what I mean is the developer can choose to write code to retry the transaction.

Comment: Yes, that's for sure. It's up to you to decide what you do when a transaction fails. But as I understood, you don't want to do anything. So you don't have to worry about it, right?

Comment: You are correct, I do not have to do anything. My issue is: transaction #2 waits until transaction #1 finishes before transaction #1 throws a concurrent modification error. This is a waste of CPU time. Especially if transaction #1 takes a bit of time to finish. I would like for transaction #2 to just fail ASAP and be done with it. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense. Perhaps you should explain this behavior directly to the Firebase team, and see what solution they can provide. And maybe also share their response with us.

Comment: I'm not using Firebase. I am using google datastore in firestore mode.

Comment: Then try to reach out Google Datastore team.

Comment: Outside of asking on stackoverflow, what other ways are there to reach out to the Google Datastore team...?

Comment: Other than [this](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) I don't know.